# Searching multiple field in ADO with C++Builder XE4

Tags: search, ado, c++builder-xe4

I'm using Locate method to search in TADOTable, but it's not work with multiple field search. (I'm searching directly on the TADOTable, therefore Not interested with SQL in this case).

The following code works fine when using single field, but does not work with multiple fields!

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
        TLocateOptions LOpts;
        LOpts.Clear();
        LOpts << loPartialKey;
        Variant VAR[1];
        VAR[0] = Variant(Edit1->Text);

        try{
          if ( ADOTable1->Locate("CompanyID;Supplier", VAR, LOpts) ){
            // Record found
          }
        }
        catch(...){}
}
```

Comment: can you show some code what you tried for?

Comment: `TCustomADODataSet.Locate()` ?

Comment: Your posted code attempts to search on one field, because you're only supplying one value. I think you're confused (or you've worded your question awkwardly). You're looking for the equivalent of the SQL `WHERE (CompanyID = 'SomeValue') or (Supplier = 'SomeValue')`, and that isn't possible with an ADOTable in a single search operation. You'll need to do two.

Comment: Aha, yes this is what I want :-) Searching one value in multiple fields `WHERE (CompanyID = 'SomeValue') or (Supplier = 'SomeValue')`. But it seems impossible with ADOTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for multiple fields in a `TADODataSet` is done pretty much the same as with any other `TDataSet`, using the [`Locate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.Locate) function and an optional `TLocateOptions`:

```
if ADODataSet1.Locate('CompanyID;Supplier', 
                      VarArrayOf([Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text]), 
                      [loPartialKey]) then
begin
  // Record found
end;
```

As your comment indicates you're actually using C++Builder and `TADOTable`, here's an example that works for it as well (compiled and tested under C++Builder XE5 in a new VCL Forms application):

```
TLocateOptions Opts;
Opts.Clear();
Opts << loPartialKey;

Variant locateValues[2];
locateValues[0] = Variant(Edit1->Text);
locateValues[1] = Variant(Edit2->Text);

if (ADOTable1->Locate("CompanyID;Supplier", VarArrayOf(locateValues, 1), Opts))
{
  // Record found.
};
```

Your comment to the original question indicates that what you actually want is to search two columns to see if either of them match a value. You can't do that with a single `Locate`, but you can do it with multiple calls (Delphi code - you should be able to easily convert it to C++ Builder given the other samples here). Of course, both columns would have to be the same data type - you can't search a numeric field and a character field for the same numeric (or character) value without converting something:

```
var
  LastName: Variant;
begin
  LastName := Edit1.Text;
  if ADOTable1.Locate('LastName', LastName, [loPartialKey]) or
     ADOTable1.Locate('CompanyName', LastName, [loPartialKey]) then
  begin
    // Record found
  end;
```

The other alternative is to use a `Filter` (again, Delphi code - straightforward C++ Builder translation):

```
AdoTable1.Filter := 'LastName = ' + QuotedStr(Edit1.Text) +
                    ' or CompanyName LIKE "' + QuotedStr(Edit1.Text) + '%"';
AdoTable1.Filtered := True;
AdoTable1.First;
// Get key values needed to locate on a full key, and then clear the filter.
```

Comment: Thank you Ken...This is my code for single field, but does not work with Multiple fields!
inline `TLocateOptions LOpts;
        LOpts.Clear();
        LOpts << loPartialKey;
        Variant VAR[1];
        VAR[0] = Variant(Edit1->Text);

        try{
          if ( ADOTable1->Locate("CompanyID", VAR, LOpts) ){
            // Record found
          }
        }
        catch(...){} // Do nothing`